# How to decode a XML file

Tags: xml, decode

I have an `XML` file that is encoded like mentioned below. Wondering if you can help me figure out how to decode it please.

Here is a sample:
`4,=]T$07'&/mtJU) Uh2EC\JhV;$  Wh|AlgU+&    j 8G#H`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This sample is far from XML. any ideas of algorithm used to encoded this ?

Comment: I just found out Python was used to encode the XML file. Now I'm really in lost territory.

Comment: After a couple of hours spent I found out how to install Python and decode the .xml file. Only problem now is when I run the .py file the output is too long in powershell and some of it is cut off. There are too many lines and most are cut off to read. Is there anyway of having the output from the code show up in a txt file? This way all the code can be read. Thank you.